# Ошибка с кастом, которой по идее не должно быть

Tags: java, android

использую вот эту [библиотеку](https://github.com/doridori/cwac-touchlist) , почти уверен, что она не при чем, но все же упомянуть лишним не будет, в общем выскакивает почему то вот такая вот ошибка, если компилю через телефон(redmi 4x), при чем выскакивает не всегда, вылезла на первых запусках, на эмуляторах стабильно отрабатывает нормально:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.yar, PID: 11406
      java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.yar.resourses.ExersiceModel
          at com.yar.ExerciseActivity$ListAdapter.getView(ExerciseActivity.java:154)
          at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2378)
          at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1326)
          at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1233)
          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19886)
          at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
          at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19886)
          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6085)
          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
          at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19886)
          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6085)
          at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:401)
          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19886)
          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6085)
          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19886)
          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6085)
          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
          at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19886)
          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6085)
          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
          at 

    com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:693)
          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19886)
          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2312)
          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1403)
          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1656)
          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6396)
          at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:876)
          at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:688)
          at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:623)
          at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:862)
          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6228)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
          at 

    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794
```

казалось бы все просто, но вот:

```
                private ArrayList<ExersiceModel> array = new ArrayList<>();
 (156 строка)   ExersiceModel exersiceModel = array.get(position);
```

весь класc:

```
public class ExerciseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String currentIntentDay;

    private ListAdapter adapter = null;
    private ArrayList<ExersiceModel> array = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercise);


        array = (ArrayList<ExersiceModel>) Serialize.myDaysMap.get(Serialize.currentDayname);


        TouchListView tlv = (TouchListView) findViewById(R.id.touch_listview);
        adapter = new ListAdapter();
        tlv.setAdapter(adapter);
        tlv.setDropListener(onDrop);
        tlv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                final ExersiceModel exersiceModel = array.get(position);

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ExerciseActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle(exersiceModel.getExersiceName());
                // LayoutInflater inflater = ExerciseActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();

                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alertdialog_layout, null);

                builder.setView(layout);

                final EditText editText1 = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.edit_AlertApproach);
                editText1.setText(String.valueOf(exersiceModel.getApproach()));
                final EditText editText2 = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.edit_AlertReiteretion);
                editText2.setText(String.valueOf(exersiceModel.getReiteration()));

                builder.setPositiveButton("Ок", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        int approach = 1;
                        int reiteration = 1;
                        try {
                            approach = Integer.valueOf(editText1.getText().toString());
                            reiteration = Integer.valueOf(editText2.getText().toString());

                            if (approach > 0 & reiteration > 0){
                                exersiceModel.setApproach(approach);
                                exersiceModel.setReiteration(reiteration);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Нужно ввести число больше нуля", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Нужно ввести число", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }



                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Отмена", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                builder.show();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }

    public void Back(View view) {
        finish();
    }

    public void button_Exercise_Add(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListExerciseActivity.class);

        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    private List<ExersiceModel> initData() {
        List<ExersiceModel> list = new ArrayList<>();


        list = Serialize.myDaysMap.get(Serialize.currentDayname);

        return list;
    }

    private TouchListView.DropListener onDrop = new TouchListView.DropListener() {
        @Override
        public void drop(int from, int to) {
            ExersiceModel item = adapter.getItem(from);
            adapter.remove(item);
            adapter.insert(item, to);
        }
    };

    class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ExersiceModel> {
        ListAdapter() {
            super(ExerciseActivity.this, R.layout.adapter_layout, array);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                            ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            if (row == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_layout, parent, false);
            }
            ExersiceModel exersiceModel = array.get(position);
            TextView labelExersice = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_exersice);
            labelExersice.setText(exersiceModel.getExersiceName());
            TextView labelApproach = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_approachName);
            labelApproach.setText(String.valueOf(exersiceModel.getApproach()));
            TextView labelReiteretion = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_reiterationName);

            labelReiteretion.setText(String.valueOf(exersiceModel.getReiteration()));
            return (row);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: На других устройствах (не xiaomi) не пробовали? Слышал что у них есть некоторые недокументированные капризы.

Comment: прозреваю, что в `Serialize.myDaysMap` где-то помещается `ArrayList` со строками. Каст в `array = (ArrayList<ExersiceModel>) Serialize.myDaysMap.get` это не выловит, потому что type erasure, поэтому проблема всплывает только при попытке взять элемент списка.

Comment: @tutaf не, нет просто других телефонов

Comment: @zRrr там пихается array <ExersiceModel>, тем более ошибка вылазит только на телефоне

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Название класса `Serialize` - намекает, что Вы там сохраняете этот список в ПЗУ.
Возможно у Вас раньше был список строк и Вы запускали приложение на телефоне, а потом Вы добавили модель, но в ПЗУ телефона остался старый список и теперь он оттуда загружается, но по коду-то мы уже ожидаем новый список с моделью.

Это что бы Вы понимали проблему на будущее, когда придётся менять тип данных в уже опубликованном приложении при обновлении.

А сейчас просто удалите существующий файл любым способом и попробуйте запустить "на чистую".

P.S. Если я не прав, то покажите нам код класса `Serialize` - проблема может быть только там.

Comment: да, скорее всего вы правы, но проверить уже не получится, т.к. после нескольких запусков проблема решилась сама, но спасибо за объяснение, а то уже под конец перед тем как задать вопрос дико стал тупить от усталости

Comment: хотя стоп, если бы там оставался старый файл, то мне бы вылетела ошибка в блоке try catch, что файл не может быть read, а тут именно ошибка, когда я создал обьект класса ExersiceModel и присвоил лист по обьекту этого класса и он не может их привести, т.к. почему то внезапно private ArrayList<ExersiceModel> имеет тип String

Comment: Почему не может быть read? Если существует файл по такому пути и с таким именем - очень даже может. А `ObjectInputStream` читает объект и ему плевать какого он типа, главное что этот тип существует и может быть создан его экземпляр.

Comment: раньше когда менял тип, у меня вылетала ошибка, ладно пусть будет так, хотя сейчас попробовал поставить стринги, запустить и вернуть обратно, снова запустить, да оно в принципе не ругается, но то что не может прочесть, просто не выводит, в любом случае ошибка крайне странная

Answer (score 1):

В `ListAdapter` определите конструктор:

```
public ListAdapter (Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<ExersiceModel> items) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
}
```

И используйте его.

Насколько я помню, достаточно реализовать один из 6-и конструкторов:

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource)
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId)
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects)
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List objects)
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List objects)
```

Вы же используете дефолтный конструктор без параметров необходимых.